# Best way for scripts in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scripting

In CodeIgniter I often have many scripts inherent to my project, for instance:

```
 <?php    
// Load many things
$this->load->model('news_model');
$this->load->helper('utility_helper');
$news = $this->news_model->get_basic_news();

// For moment no news
$view_datas['news']['check'] = false;

if ($news) {

    $view_datas['news'] = array(

        'check' => true,
        'news' => _humanize_news($news)

        );
}
?>
```

This script is used in different controllers, at the moment I create a `scripts` folder and I import it like that: `include(APPPATH . 'scripts/last_news.php');` I'm quite sure it's not the best way to handle this problem. Any thoughts on that?

**Update:** 
A solution given in the answers is to use a `helper` or a `library`. 
Let's imagine a rewrite of my previous code:

```
class Scripts {

public function last_news() {
    // Load many things to use
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('news_model');
    $CI->load->model('utility_helper');

    $news = $CI->news_model->get_basic_news();

    // Avoid the rest of code
}

}
```

Comment: I usually make these helpers.. and include them in autoload

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new library and load that library whereever you require?
e.g.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Newclass {

    public function get_news($limit)
    {
      //return news
    }
}

/* End of file Newsclass.php */
```

In your controllers

```
$this->load->library('newsclass');
$this->newsclass->get_news($limit);
```

Or another idea is to create helper functions.

Comment: Yes it's a solution to put all in an `scripts` class, but imagine i have got like 15/16 scripts, so 16 methods, for speed exec it's not viable ...

Comment: And one other thing, if i create class or helper to make this, usualy i load many models or helper, so the solution is to make a `$CI =& get_instance(); ` so take the Super Object CI, and this way is slow. I use Codeigniter because i like the faster time to exec but i think we have got a problem with this ...